# How do i print a multi array item from a dictionary to my worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below readmultiitems function which creates a dictionary for me , I then print the keys into a worksheet via a transpose function which works. I then want to print the corresponding Items for each key into my worksheet across 3 columns (i.e a column for each array of items without looping through each of the items.
can someone please help - the last transpose function for the items below does not work - I get a runtime error method  transpose of object 'worksheet function' failed.

I also have clasportfoliocomp as a class module as below

I have spent ages on this but am stumped!
any help much appreciated.

Many thanks

```
Dim lastrow2 As Long, dict_count As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim dict As Dictionary
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("cs_CM_Input")

    
    
    ws1.Activate
    lastrow2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws1.range("Portfolio_comp")) + 1
    Set dict = ReadMultiItems
    dict_count = dict.Count
    'Debug.Print dict.Items
    ws1.Cells(lastrow2, 3).Resize(dict_count, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    ws1.Cells(lastrow2, 4).Resize(dict_count, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)


End Sub


Private Function ReadMultiItems() As Dictionary

    ' Declare and create the Dictionary
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim le_id As String
    Dim rg As range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim oComp As ClsPortfolioComp
    
    ' Get the worksheet and workbook and range
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Combined_IBRR_Lot")
    Set rg = ws1.range("Portfolio_Comp_Data")
 
    ' read through the data
    For i = 2 To rg.rows.Count
        le_id = rg.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 8).Value
        ' Create a new clsCustomer object
        Set oComp = New ClsPortfolioComp
        
        If Not dict.Exists(le_id) Then
        ' Set the values
        oComp.le_id = rg.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 8).Value
        oComp.Elig_weight = rg.Cells(i, 1).Value
        oComp.Moodys = rg.Cells(i, 2).Value
        oComp.Evest = rg.Cells(i, 3).Value
        
        ' Add the new clsPortfolioComp object to the dictionary
        dict.Add oComp.le_id, oComp
        Else: End If
    Next i
    
    ' Return the dictionary to the Main sub
    Set ReadMultiItems = dict

End Function

Public Evest As String
Public Moodys As String
Public Elig_weight As String
Public le_id As String
```

i tried converting to an array

`item_array = dict.Items ws1.Cells(lastrow2, 4).Resize(dict_count, 4).Value = item_array`

but got an object defined or application defined runtime error

Comment: Why don't you want to loop through each of the items ?

Comment: FYI, even if you have a method that "Doesn't" loop through all the items like Range("A1:A5").value = 5... it's still looping through all the items... it's just VBA is kind of taking care of that behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to take a dictionary and:
**A)** Covert it to an array
**B)** Print it to a Worksheet

```
Option Explicit
Sub Dictionary_To_Array_And_Worksheet()
    
    ' Variables
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim KeyArray
    Dim OutArray
    Dim I As Long
    
    ' Build Dictionary
    Set Dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dict.Add "a", "Awesome Apple"
    Dict.Add "b", "Bumble Bee"
    Dict.Add "c", "Cheap Charlie"
    Dict.Add "d", "Dark Door"
    
    ' Print Keys to KeyArray
    KeyArray = Dict.keys
    ' Resize Output Array
    ReDim OutArray(1 To Dict.Count, 1 To 2)
    ' Iterate through Dictionary and move data to output array
    For I = 1 To Dict.Count
       Debug.Print I & " - " & KeyArray(I - 1) & " = " & Dict(KeyArray(I - 1))
       OutArray(I, 1) = KeyArray(I - 1)
       OutArray(I, 2) = Dict(KeyArray(I - 1))
    Next I
    
    ' Output to worksheet
    Sheet4.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(OutArray, 1), 2) = OutArray
    
End Sub
```

Example of output:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looping is still your best method